# How to add a label to radio button via the state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, label

I have created a form via the state, a bit different approach to many others which I am already regretting. I want to know how to add a label to each radio button. I could have taken a different approach and created the form in the render but instead I have attempted it this way and now I cant solve this issue.

```
this.state = {
            items: [],
            filteredItems: [],
               Form: {
                searchBar: {
                    elementType: 'input',
                    elementConfig: {
                        className: 'Input_Box',
                        type: 'text',
                        placeholder: 'Moon'
                    },
                    value: '',
                    validation: {
                    required: true,
                    minLength: 3,
                    maxLength: 25
                    },
                    valid: true
                },
                   checkImage: {
                    elementType: 'input',
                    elementConfig: {
                        className: 'CheckBox',
                        type: 'checkbox',
                    },
                    defaultvalue: 'Image',
                    validation: {
                    required: true,
                    },
                    valid: true,
                    checked: true,
                },
                   checkVideo: {
                    elementType: 'input',
                    elementConfig: {
                        className: 'CheckBox',
                        type: 'checkbox',
                    },
                    defaultvalue: 'Video',
                    validation: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    valid: true,
                    checked: false,
                }
            },
            formIsValid: false
}
```

Any advice on how to add a simple label on-top of the radio buttons and maybe lay them out beside each other in-line, thanks!

Comment: This would be very difficult without writing declaratively. I do not exactly know how this config gets converted in the render, but one way to solve the issue is to create a `RadioButton` component that accepts label as a prop. You can then pass it from config. But even then styling that with respect to other components would be a challenge.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure what to do really, maybe I just change the whole form itself. @Easwar